# iPXE: Unregistered SAN device 0x80

Tags: pxe

I'm trying [iPXE](https://ipxe.org/). From the [sanboot examples](https://ipxe.org/cmd/sanboot) you should be able to boot from an ISO from an HTTP target.

```
sanboot http://boot.ipxe.org/freedos/fdfullcd.iso
```

But that doesn't work for me, any suggestions?
I have build iPXE and flashed it on a USB stick.

```
iPXE> dhcp
iPXE> ping google.com
64 bytes from 172.217.17.110: seq=1
64 bytes from 172.217.17.110: seq=2
Finished: Operation canceled (http://ipxe.org/0b072095)
iPXE> sanboot http://boot.ipxe.org/freedos/fdfullcd.iso
Registered SAN device 0x80
Booting from SAN device 0x80
Boot from SAN device 0x80
Boot from SAN device 0x80 failed: Error 0x3d222083 (http://ipxe.org/3d222083)
Unregistered SAN device 0x80
iPXE>
```

What I tried:

- Building iPXE with the debug option `DEBUG=efi_block`
- Switching between Legacy and UEFI in `BIOS >> Advanced >> CSM Configuration >> Storage`

EDIT:
Works with debian:

```
sanboot http://gemmei.ftp.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL with the second error code suggests you're using the UEFI version of iPXE, since it error description in the linked page refers to UEFI-only parts of the iPXE code.

But FreeDOS does not work with UEFI at all, and so the `fdfullcd.iso` is not bootable with UEFI.

To boot FreeDOS on your system, you would have to enable the CSM (set to Legacy) *and* use a version of iPXE intended for Legacy BIOS instead of `ipxe.efi`.

It is unclear how you're starting iPXE in the first place. Are you using a PXE network boot, or loading iPXE locally from a CD or an USB stick, or running `ipxe.lkrn` from GRUB, or something else? This will have a major impact on your possibilities to get a Legacy BIOS version of iPXE started in order to boot a FreeDOS ISO image.

Please *edit your question* to add more information; I will then edit my answer to add more advice if I can. Or someone else may write another answer if they figure out the problem first.